# My images code does not working in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: html

I am a newbie in coding and I try to find out what makes my HTML images idle?
Can you have a look for this?

```
<p> My Most Favorite Plantnete - Uranus
img src "Uranus2.png" alt "Uranus" id "Pic3"
</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit this into:

```
<p>My Most Favorite Planet - Uranus
<img src="Uranus2.png" alt="Uranus" id="Pic3">
</p>
```